# Import CSV file into sqlite database using cordova sqlite plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on cordova App where i need to insert records into sqlite database from csv file.
I know how it is done on cmd.

`sqlite> .mode csv table_name`
`sqlite> .import file_name.csv table_name`

Is there a way to achieve the same using cordova sqlite plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It's something that the cordova sqlite plugin doesn't have.
You could use this plugin instead:

https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy

Without the plugin you could make a manual read and write operation to the sql.
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/read-existing-sqlite-database-file-and-load-data/94167/31